# Extracting addresses from Word in automator

Tags: automator

I am trying to use automator to create a print plugin that will print my Microsoft Word letter and also extract a mailing address from the document and then run a Keyboard Maestro command which exports the address to my postage program, Endicia, and prints an envelope.

The problem is I have my letterhead at the top which has my address in it, and I need it to skip that and find the mailing address after the date in my letter.

Is there an easy way to do that in automator?

Thanks!
Ethan

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of using an Automator Print Plugin that you use an AppleScript by typing in the script in the application: /Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app

Automator works best when there is an Automator action that gives you pretty much what you need.  I think that a Print Plugin might be good to move the PDF file, or rename it, or attach it to an email and send it out, but I don't know how to get into the content of a PDF document and extract the data that you need.

You could check and see what Automator actions that Word provides, but I don't believe that an Automator workflow saved as a Print Plugin is the right tool for this job since the workflow would receive the PDF file as its input which I believe would make it harder to extract the address from that it would be to extract the address from your Word document.

Using an AppleScript, you should be able to first extract the address that you need from your Word document and then print the Word document using AppleScript.

It would help to have a copy of your Word document.  You could email it to me if you would like and I could help you some more.

-- Kaydell
kaydell@yahoo.com
[Learn By Mac: http://learnbymac.com](http://learnbymac.com)